# 'Parse java...' stuck in IntelliJ while Build Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2020.2 and I am trying to run big project but when click `Build Project` then it's getting stuck with `Parsing java...` (for smaller project it works perfectly). I can add that in IntelliJ Idea 2019.1.3 I can build this project in less than minute. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: @y.bedrov I didn't know there are hidden logs, thanks. I just found there: `JAVAC_PROCESS[STDERR]: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: Please try to increase build heap size in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler".

Comment: @y.bedrov works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to increase build heap size in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler".

Answer (score 0):

I have similar kind of issue. I have root project(r1) and it has m1, m2...m30 modules in it.

r1

- m1
- m2
  ....
  -m30

When i open r1 project and run one of the integration test in m2 it takes around 30 mins but when i open module m2 as root and run integration test executing in <2 mins

any pointers to fix this issue?